# How to find which WDS access point I'm connected to?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wds

I'm reposting [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7613/how-to-find-which-wds-access-point-im-connected-to)  I asked on the [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) SE, bacause I have been redirected to Super User.

I have successfully set up two Linksys routers running DD-WRTv24 to do WDS. They have the same SSID, but different static local IP addresses. There is no security: it's just for testing; no Internet connection.

When I open my notebook, I see the SSID shared by the routers in the list of WiFi access points, and I can connect to it. Once connected, I can ping both routers' local IP addresses, so I know that the WDS is working. But I can't find a way to find out which of them I have actually connected to.

I wouldn't like to have different SSIDs, because I plan to have the access points hand-off users to one another, and I want it to be transparent for the users. I configured one AP to distribute DHCP IP addresses in one range, and the other in another range, so I can discover which AP I connected to at first, but I want a way to discover which AP I'm connected to *now*, so that I can find out whether the hand-off actually occurred.

Comment: IPCONFIG /ALL doesn't provide the info via the gateway address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your computer which MAC address your wifi is connected **to**. This is typically reported somewhere in the details about network connections. Exactly where depends on OS and version to an excessive extent for a concise answer.

Alternatively, look in the access point control software to see which one says you are attached to it.

Comment: Answering "somewhere" on the question "where" can't be regarded as an answer.

Comment: And yet it seems to have been adequate for the questioner. Indeed, you appear to be confused about the where question and the somewhere answer since they are **not the same where.** Feel free to write a better answer if you find this one so inadequate. I can't be bothered to set up a system with wireless router software I haven't used in years and don't anticipate using ever again to answer in more detail, and in fact, the more general answer applies to more setups than the specific answer would; the Laptop OS is not specified at all, so a more specific answer there is not possible, IMHO.

Comment: Sorry, I have this question myself and my question was closed and redirected here. So, I am forced to downvote, since this answer is bad for me.

Comment: So, figure out how it applies to your specific case. bssid is the magic acronym and this will show you the way. But that's only one specific case among many possible cases... https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chad/2011/08/02/tip-42-viewing-detailed-windows-7-wireless-information/

Comment: Good! So, how to know `BSSID` of currently connected `AP`?

Comment: Overcome your unwillingness to read things for yourself? It's spelled out in the linked article.

Comment: Sorry, I can't remove downvote until answer changes. Would you mind to include this spell in the answer? It will be really better with it!